# Not able present viewcontroller over splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have viewcontroller presented on timeout notification, if window's rootViewController is
 Splitviewcontroller then presented view controllers view is going below the Master controller of Splitview controller

here is my code to present view controller

```
- (void) applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif {

if (![self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]) {
        NumberKeyPadViewController *controller = [[NumberKeyPadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NumberKeyPadViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
}}
```

[image]

Comment: i got this link  but  i am not using Storyboard
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834497/presenting-modal-viewcontroller-over-splitviewcontroller-at-app-startup

Comment: give me reason for downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got below solution to the problem

1) present view controller from [youtsplitviewcontroller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];